# html5 site with drupal

Tags: drupal, html

can I implement an HTML5 site with drupal?
If yes, how? And which version of drupal I need?
Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Michele

Answer (score 4):

You can create any markup with Drupal. An explaination of how it's done is too comprehensive to write here.

From the sound of your question, it seems like you are new to Drupal. Try looking at the [Drupal handbooks](http://drupal.org/handbook) to get an idea of what you can do with Drupal.

Also HTML5 is not magic in any way, it's just a different doctype that supports some new tags. Drupal's standard output would probably fit HTML5 if you changed the doctype accordingly in your theme.

Answer (score 2):

I found this : http://nimbupani.com/creating-html-5-theme-for-drupal-6.html

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do HTML5, doesn't matter if its Drupal or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This year's [DrupalCamp Colorado](http://drupalcampcolorado.org/) site, for example, is HTML5 and (of course) Drupal. All current versions of Drupal (5, 6, and 7) have flexible markup systems, so that's irrelevant. And "how?" is a really general question with no indication of your knowledge of theming in Drupal and/or your understanding of HTML5. But basically, you take HTML5 markup, and you put it in your theme. That's it.

It sounds like maybe all the hype around HTML5 has convinced you it's something significantly more complicated than HTML4 or XHTML. It's not.